# Obtaining underlying class from org.eclipse.jdt.core.IClassFile

Tags: java, eclipse, reflection, eclipse-jdt

I have a list of `org.eclipse.jdt.core.IClassFile`, what will be the most simple way to get the actual class file (for reflection)?

The option that I see, in case it's a jar file , is to load jar with `JarFile`
(I can get jar and package from IClassFile parents) 
then to iterate over all entries in `JarFile` and then ,u sing a classloader to load that class.

But maybe there is a better way...

Comment: You can get a huge amount of information from the `IClassFile`, unless you actually want to run the code you probably don't need the actual class.

Comment: I need to get list of field this, I believe I can get. but in some cases I also need to extract source code of constructor (after decompile)

Comment: If you really want to decompile you need a decompiler (which JDT is not). Instead JDT lets you navigate to the **source attachment** of a library, which may be much better.